# I have an issue to handle multiple socket-io instances events within a single function in node js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have an issue to handle multiple socket-io instances events within a single function in node js

```
var io = require("socket.io-client")
var sessionKey = "123"
var socArr = []
var key = 'sessionKey=' + sessionKey
var name = sessionKey
socArr[name] = io.connect('https://client.mindolife.com:8888', {
reconnect: true,
'force new connection': true,
query: key
})

var sessionKey1 = "234"
var key1 = 'sessionKey=' + sessionKey1
var name1 = sessionKey1

socArr[name1] = io.connect('https://client.mindolife.com:8888', {
reconnect: true,
'force new connection': true,
query: key1
})
```

//Establishing connection

```
socArr[name].on('connect', function(event) {
console.log('Event Instance 1 connected')
});

socArr[name1].on('connect', function(event) {
console.log('Event Instance 2 connected')
});
```

// This below code need to be implemented within single function dynamically

```
socArr[name].on('changeControlState', function(event) {
console.log("Instance 1", event.eventData)
});

socArr[name1].on('changeControlState', function(event) {
console.log("Instance 2", event.eventData)
});
```

Comment: Could you please format your code and add some descriptive text elaborating on the exact problem you are facing? That way it is easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I underdand well, you want to avoid to repeat you callback functions definition so you can use a factory to do something like:

```
function setConnectHandler (sockName) {
  socObj[sockName].on('connect', function(event) {
    console.log(`Event ${sockName} connected`)
  });
}
```

and then call it like `setConnectHandler('name1')`